# Not able to install alloy

Tags: titanium, appcelerator, titanium-alloy

I am getting this error while trying to download alloy in titanium. It seems proxy error but i double checked there is no proxy setting.How can i get it through.
npm ERR! Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND.
Here is the Log file

```
   0 info it worked if it ends with ok
    1 verbose cli [ 'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe',
    1 verbose cli   'c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js',
    1 verbose cli   'install',
    1 verbose cli   '-g',
    1 verbose cli   'alloy' ]
    2 info using npm@1.2.15
    3 info using node@v0.10.1
    4 verbose read json C:\Users\tarak\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
    5 verbose read json C:\Users\tarak\AppData\Roaming\npm\package.json
    6 verbose cache add [ 'alloy', null ]
    7 verbose cache add name=undefined spec="alloy" args=["alloy",null]
    8 verbose parsed url { protocol: null,
    8 verbose parsed url   slashes: null,
    8 verbose parsed url   auth: null,
    8 verbose parsed url   host: null,
    8 verbose parsed url   port: null,
    8 verbose parsed url   hostname: null,
    8 verbose parsed url   hash: null,
    8 verbose parsed url   search: null,
    8 verbose parsed url   query: null,
    8 verbose parsed url   pathname: 'alloy',
    8 verbose parsed url   path: 'alloy',
    8 verbose parsed url   href: 'alloy' }
    9 silly lockFile 8d809cba-alloy alloy
    10 verbose lock alloy C:\Users\tarak\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\8d809cba-alloy.lock
    11 silly lockFile 8d809cba-alloy alloy
    12 silly lockFile 8d809cba-alloy alloy
    13 verbose addNamed [ 'alloy', '' ]
    14 verbose addNamed [ null, '' ]
    15 silly lockFile b2f8915b-alloy alloy@
    16 verbose lock alloy@ C:\Users\tarak\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\b2f8915b-alloy.lock
    17 silly addNameRange { name: 'alloy', range: '', hasData: false }
    18 verbose url raw alloy
    19 verbose url resolving [ 'https://registry.npmjs.org/', './alloy' ]
    20 verbose url resolved https://registry.npmjs.org/alloy
    21 info trying registry request attempt 1 at 18:54:45
    22 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/alloy
    23 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    24 info trying registry request attempt 2 at 18:55:03
    25 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/alloy
    26 info retry will retry, error on last attempt: Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    27 info trying registry request attempt 3 at 18:56:05
    28 http GET https://registry.npmjs.org/alloy
    29 silly lockFile b2f8915b-alloy alloy@
    30 silly lockFile b2f8915b-alloy alloy@
    31 error Error: tunneling socket could not be established, cause=getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND
    31 error     at ClientRequest.onError (c:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\npm\node_modules\request\tunnel.js:161:17)
    31 error     at ClientRequest.g (events.js:175:14)
    31 error     at ClientRequest.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    31 error     at CleartextStream.socketErrorListener (http.js:1500:9)
    31 error     at CleartextStream.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:95:17)
    31 error     at Socket.onerror (tls.js:1336:17)
    31 error     at Socket.EventEmitter.emit (events.js:117:20)
    31 error     at net.js:807:16
    31 error     at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
    32 error If you need help, you may report this log at:
    32 error     <http://github.com/isaacs/npm/issues>
    32 error or email it to:
    32 error     <npm-@googlegroups.com>
    33 error System Windows_NT 6.1.7600
    34 error command "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "c:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "alloy"
    35 error cwd C:\Users\tarak
    36 error node -v v0.10.1
    37 error npm -v 1.2.15
    38 error code ECONNRESET
    39 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
```

Comment: can you post the details in `C:\Users\tarak\npm-debug.log`

Comment: maybe they have issues with their SQL connection at the moment. i tried in browser and got a warning about issues with their certificate. Are you experiencing this problems already for a longer period?

Comment: I tried all day long, but no luck.And regarding the certificate issue i don't think that could be an issue in npm.